# Pagination issue with wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, pagination

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. Sorry in advance if I do not follow the "rules". Thank you for letting me know.

The context is the following:
I am coding a webpage geolocalising people from an association and display their positions on a google map within a wordpress framework. When I click on their marker I display an info window with their info. 
On the map, I can filter/search the people with a form (for example look only at the people named Paul). So far all this working.

My problem is the following:
When I do a search I would like to display the results underneath the map. As I can have quite a few results (let's say typically around 100) , I'ld like to display them with some pagination. Basically I'ld love to do something like this http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/ ... but I am having some hard time implementing it :(

And now the code !

I start by creating the div to host the pagination menu

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Result </h1>
    <div id="results">  
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I load the related libraries

```
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.paginate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally I write the pagination code in itself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#results").paginate({
                count   : 20,
                start   : 1,
                display     : 8,
                border          : true,
                border_color        : '#fff',
                text_color          : '#fff',
                background_color        : 'black',  
                border_hover_color  : '#ccc',
                text_hover_color    : '#000',
                background_hover_color  : '#fff', 
                images          : false,
                mouse           : 'press'
            });
        });
</script>
```

Nevertheless when I do so, I don't have the pagination menu and the console is returning me

```
TypeError: $jaer(...).on is not a function
```

within the .js file ...

According to mister Google it seems like this might be due to a definition conflict of the $ symbol. But this issue should be avoided by using the jQuery(function ($) { } isn't??

Comment: Have you checked the console output to see if the paths are correct for the js files being loaded? The best way to do scripts is enqueue in functions.

Comment: is `$jaer = jQuery` somewhere?

Comment: I can access the files with the paths returned in html so it seems correct.
In the pagination.js file I do have 
    $jaer = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Ok, I think it's the version of `jQuery` you're using, check my answer below.

Comment: Also I don't see `$jaer` in the source code `http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/jquery.paginate.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

```
 (function($) {
     $("#results").paginate({
            count   : 20,
            start   : 1,
            display     : 8,
            border          : true,
            border_color        : '#fff',
            text_color          : '#fff',
            background_color        : 'black',  
            border_hover_color  : '#ccc',
            text_hover_color    : '#000',
            background_hover_color  : '#fff', 
            images          : false,
            mouse           : 'press'
        });
```

})(jQuery)

## EDIT

After doing some investigation, this isn't the issue, it seems like `$` is defined, I've just never seen this particular syntax before: http://jsfiddle.net/UL69C/5/

Not sure about the rest of your code, but `$` will be undefined in the above example.

## EDIT 02

I think it's probably a result of `$jaer` not being defined ( `$jaer = jQuery` or`$jaer = $` ) like in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UL69C/9/

## EDIT 03

Ok, it looks like the *version* of `jQuery` you're using is older, in that case `on` isn't supported... use `.delegate() or .live()`

Comment: Ya, I just updated my answer. That's not the issue, just haven't seen that setup like that before.

Comment: If I am right, my syntax will make the script wait for the page to be loaded while yours will execute right away.

Comment: I think the issue is that `$jaer = jQuery` isn't defined.

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll  look at it and get back to you (I'm not a web ninja at all ...).

Comment: No worries, it's usually just a process of elimination :-)

Comment: mmm sorry to ask this but I don't see any on() in the script ... I don't know what I need to change ...

Comment: I think it might be to the fact that I am loading two different version of jquery ...

Comment: The error specifics the use of the `on` method `$jaer(...).on` and the library that you reference above doesn't support `on` which was added in ` 1.7`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It was due to a conflict between versions of jQuery. The version 1.8 was loaded by Wordpress (I am not the only user of the site) and I was loading the version 1.3.